# superclass --- package vs class

Tags: java, class, javadoc, superclass

`RandomGenerator` class is a subclass of `Random` class. They both have different packages.  `RandomGenerator` is in `acm.util` package and `Random` class is in `java.util` class.

I don't understand how different packages fit within different classes. A package is a collection of different classes. Is this correct? If `java.util`package has different classes in it and one of those classes is Random class. Does Random class have the acm.util packages in it? Are packages extensions of classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package information can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html) 
and class inheritance can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#d5e9916) 8.2-2, 8.2-3 and 8.2-4

In short to subclass and subclass-able class both needs not to be in same package. I guess this is what puzzling you, how can one package can subclass from another package ?

Answer (score 3):

The relationship from class to package is a 1-to-many-relationship.
1 class belongs to exactly one package, but a package can contain several classes (or further sub-packages).

The package-relationship of a class is completely orthogonal (independent) to the inheritance but can influence the visibility of the classes members.

Maybe you are familiar with C++ or C#, they have the concept of "namespaces" to exactly distinguish between same-named classes. Java solves that problem with packages. Each package can contain a class with the same name only once  - so the fully-qualified name of the class (like `java.util.random`) is unique.

Answer (score 0):

The packages are like folders, is a way of order your classes.

You can have classes that implements or extends from libraries in very different packages. The important thing is that you must follow some "rules":

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html

Comment: there is more to it than just ordering your classes

Comment: From "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html": Programs are organized as sets of packages. Each package has its own set of names for types, which helps to prevent name conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about that in Java Language Specification:

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html
>   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html

Comment: You might like to point to a particular section as the JLS takes quite a while to read and understand end to end. ;)

Comment: It would be good for the topic's author to read all about packages and classes, but overview is as the first sections in both links.